# Рекурсивный http запрос Angular + RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular, rxjs

При запросе на urlFirst получаем данные. Если данные содержат ключ со значением 'nextPage', нужно сделать запрос на urlNextPage, чтобы получить дополнительные данные и так далее, до тех пор пока в ответе с urlNextPage не будет ключа nextPage.
urlNextPage в каждом ответе приходят разные.

Объект имеет такую структуру:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "price": 784,
    "links": [{
        "status": "selfPage",
        "url": "urlSelf"
      },
      {
        "status": "nextPage",
        "url": "urlNextPage"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Нужно собрать данные из urlFirst и со всех рекурсивных вызовов urlNextPage в один массив.

Пробовал сделать обычной рекурсией, но все правильно собрать не получается.

```
let arr = [];
getData() {
    this.httpGeneralService.getDataServer(`urlFirst `)
      .subscribe(e => {
        this.arr.push(e.price);
        this.recursive(e);
      });
  }

  recursive(e) {
    for (const obj in e.links) {
      if (e.links[obj].status === 'nextPage') {
        this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer(e.links[obj].url)
          .pipe(map(item => {
            this.arr.push(item.price);
            return item;
          }))
          .subscribe(z => {
            this.recursive(z);
          });
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте `for` циклы и `if` условия в связке с RxJS. Для этого есть функция `from`, которая параметром принимает 3 типа аргументов - поток, `Promise` и массив + оператор `filter`.

Что тут происходит? Мы делаем запрос на `urlFirst`, получаем объект со свойством `links` (если я правильно понял с вашего кода).

Используя `from` в цикле идем по массиву `links` и фильтруем ссылку у которой статус равен `nextPage`. После этого вызываем `getDataFromJsonServer`, который также возвращает объект в потоке со свойствами `price` и `links`. Пушим `price` в массив и опять вызываем функцию `recursive` с этими ссылками.

```
getData() {
    this.httpGeneralService.getDataServer(`urlFirst `).pipe(
        tap(({ price }) => this.array.push(price)),
        switchMap(({ links }) => this.recursive(links))
    ).subscribe(() => {
        console.log(this.array);
    });
}

recursive(links) {
    return from(links).pipe(
        filter(({ status }) => status === 'nextPage'),
        mergeMap(({ url }) => this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer(url).pipe(
            map(({ price, links }) => {
                this.array.push(price);
                return links;
            }),
            mergeMap((links) => this.recursive(links))
        ))
    );
}
```

Comment: Суппер! Спасибо! Да, приходит объект со свойством links, который имеет немного другую структуру (я добавил в вопросе) . Мне не понятно, как такую структуру отфильтровать с помощью from/filter

Comment: Я уже было смотрел в сторону expand для рекурсии

Comment: ну смотрите, у вас массив `links` - его нужно передать в функцию `from`, `from` будет в цикле идти по нему (то что вы делаете с помощью `for`), внутри фильтра мы уже получаем элементы из массива (объект `{ status: '...', url: '...' }`), в фильтр передаем предикат, что дальнейшие действия мы должны совершать только для элементов массива у которых `status === 'nextPage'`, `expand` вам не поможет

Comment: если `status === 'nextPage'` - то мы берем `url` из объекта и делаем новый запрос, получаем ответ, пушим `price` в массив и опять вызываем `this.recursive` для нового массива `links`

Comment: У меня просто в MergeMap, url линтер выделяет как: Свойство "url" не существует в типе "{ status: any; }".

Comment: укажите тип для `links`, у вас должен быть интерфейс типа `interface Link { status: string; url: string; }` - `recursive(links: Link[])`

Comment: Да, добавил. Странно, теперь ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: у вас что-то намудрено с моделями, что возвращает `getDataFromJsonServer`?

Comment: Да, это у меня на последнем ответе сервера undefined сюда приходит  return from(links).pipe(...

Comment: Отчего-то console.log(this.array) в getData() не срабатывает.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой на Ваш взгляд хороший ресурс по RxJs ?

Comment: сложно сказать, я сам изучал просто методом тыка проб и ошибок ;)

Comment: Снимаю шляпу) Выручаете меня не в первый раз)